# EDG binary tarball not available

Tags: rose-compiler-framework

I am getting EDG tarball download error while installing ROSE compiler version 0.9.10.54

The error is -

Downloading EDG binary tarball: roseBinaryEDG-4-9-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gnu-4.8-4.82daf656b47602afa41dc38d5a30fa107fbc1e7b.tar.gz
error: the EDG binary tarball is not available (or the web site is not reachable).
Please contact rose-public@nersc.gov to troubleshoot this error.
make[4]: *** [EDG.tar.gz] Error 1

The gcc version in my machine is 4.8.5.
As GCC 4.8 is not supported by ROSE anymore, can anyone please tell me for which version of GCC, the EDG tarball is now being distributed?
Also, will ROSE version 0.9.10.54 support this EDG tarball?
If not, please guide me regarding download steps for latest ROSE compiler.

Thanks,

Yogita